# how to set a color for check box in angularjs with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

here is my code. Please find a solution for this.

```
 <div class="list">
        <ul class="items-list">
            <li ng-repeat="listService in servicesList">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="listService.selected" />
              <img ng-src="{{listService.img}}" title="{{listService.name}}" alt="{{listService.name}}" />
              <span>{{listService.name}}</span>
            </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: Maybe try `ng-style`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

ng-class is what your looking for:

```
  <ANY class="ng-class: expression;"> ... </ANY>
```

And the expression can be a css class

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `ng-class="someClass"`and write this `someClass` style in your css file or you can use `ng-style={style: expression}`. But I would prefer `ng-class` over `ng-style` because I really dont think inline-css is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS styling to the .coloredInput class.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="listService.selected" ng-class="{ 'coloredInput': listService.selected }" />
```